# How do i use zxing to get the raw data from the barcode?

Tags: qr-code, zxing

I have the situation where i want to get the raw data contents of a qr code. This qrcode contains data stored in a binary form (i.e. its actually a zip archive, deflate format, so its non text i.e. binary).

I am using the latest version of the zxing library in java 11.

Result.getRawBytes was the obvious first attempt, but it doesnt seem to be delivering what I want. Actually, I am not sure what it supposed to deliver (maybe I just misunderstand the function?). I am kind of at a loss here?

EDIT; the qr code contains a small preamble (14 bytes) which are using UTF-8 and acts as an identifiying header, these 14 bytesa re immediately followed by the payload that consists of compressed data (using the deflate function in java). and the raw bytes are stored here. The whole specification of the contents can be found here (as its an UIC standard); https://www.era.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/docs/recommendation/era_rec122_tap_tsi_revision_recommendation_technical_document_b12_en.pdf, page 36 and onward for those so inclined.

EDIT 2;
When using Neoreader i get the following set of raw bytes from the QR code;